# PyPI index vs simple index

Tags: python, pypi

I've seen mention both an `index` and a `simple index` in relation to PyPI, an example is here in the [devpi documentation](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/userman/devpi_indices.html#use-sub-command). Is there some difference between the two indexes? Are they the same or do they have different access controls or functions for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "simple" index protocol is read-only, intended for automated use, and is defined in [PEP 503](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/). Other protocols with more functionality may be defined by particular repository servers, but are probably only usable with that server's own tools.

Answer (score 1):

As for https://pypi.org/ and some other Python repositories:

1. `https://pypi.org/pypi` index (XML RPC URL) is used by the `pip search` command.
   For example:

```
pip search --index https://pypi.org/pypi twine
```

https://pypi.org/ deprecated this feature in their repo. But you can still use it in private repositories.

2. `https://pypi.org/simple` is an index, that is used by the `pip install` command.
   For example:

```
pip install --index-url https://pypi.org/simple twine
```

To assess `simple` via web, add a slash at the end of `https://pypi.org/simple/` if there is no automatic redirect.

By the way, `--index` has a corresponding `PIP_INDEX` environment variable and `--index-url` has a corresponding `PIP_INDEX_URL` variable.